# Menu Toggle on Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is my problem.

I'm trying to make a navigation which pops-up or slides down or fade-in (whatever) when you scroll the page down. The issue that I have is that, in one page (index page) I have a video background, and that navigation on scroll doesn't show up at all when you scroll down, on the other pages where there's no video it works fine.

Code:

```js
var num = 300;

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
    $('#topSmallNav').addClass('showtopbar');
  } else {
    $('#topSmallNav').removeClass('showtopbar');
  }
});
```

```css
video#bgvid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -10;
  background-position: top center;
}
.showtopbar {
  display: block!important;
  z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="topSmallNav">
  <a href="#">Tryout</a>
</div>
<video autoplay loop preload="auto" id="bgvid">
  <source src="video/girl.web" type="vide/web">
    <source src="video/girl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: do you have a wrapping page load for the binding?

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gu531aay/1/) works for me scroll and check

Comment: Yes guys i know it works in that fiddle, because it works in the other pages, the problem is when i have a <video></video> in a background, it only works in mozilla...